# "To correct" or "to correcting"?

Tags: verbs, infinitives, word-form

Please tell me whether this sentence is correct.

> The first step to correcting a mistake is patience.

I think that after *to* the verb must be in its infinitive form. Am I mistaken?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct. It should be

> The first step to **correct** a mistake is patience.

but you could also say

> The first step **in correcting** a mistake is patience.

meaning

> The first step **in** (the process of) **correcting** a mistake is patience.

Comment: Nice answer; _in correcting_ is the form I would most likely use.

Comment: I believe you're mistaken.  I searched COCA for "the first step to" and found 286 results.  I took the first 100, discarded one, and checked the remaining 99 instances to see if they were followed by verbs or nouns.  Only 13 were followed by verbs; the remaining 86 were followed by nouns.  Of these 86 nouns, 68 were gerunds (as in "the first step to correcting").  This supports my intuition as a native speaker: both forms are correct, and the one you prefer is the less common of the two.

Answer (score 4):

There are actually two different *to*s.

One is the *infinitive marker*, which tells us that what follows is the *infinitive* form of the verb.

> I want ***to*** correct my mistakes.

The other is the *preposition*, which marks its object—the noun or noun phrase which follows it—as the direction or goal of an action.

> He is driving ***to*** London.

In your example, the *to* is in fact the preposition: you take a first step *to* or *toward* a goal. (In fact, most native speakers would use *toward* rather than *to*). Consequently it must take the form of the verb which can act as a noun: the *-ing* form, which is called a gerund.

> The first step toward ***correcting*** a mistake is patience.

(Note that the *marked infinitive* form of the verb can be used as a noun, too—for instance, ***To correct*** one’s mistakes is virtuous—but it is **not** used as the object of a preposition.)

Comment: +1. Also in British English, we would prefer *towards* rather than *toward* (in American English *toward* is preferred).

Answer (score 2):

After "to" a *verb* must be in its infinitive form. You are not mistaken there. Then it must be:

> The first step to correct    a mistake is patience.

But "correcting" can also be a substantive, i.e. it is also possible:

> The first step to **(the)** correcting **of** a mistake is patience.

In that case the *of* would be missing (while the *correcting* would be right in this case).

It is also possible to use *for* plus gerund, i.e.:

> The first step **for** correcting a mistake is patience.

Here *correcting* is right, but *to* is wrong and needs to be replaced by *for*.

Answer (score 0):

The infinitive is generally used to show purpose or intention, as in the example sentence you wrote. The example sentence can be rewritten as:

> Patience is the first step to correct a mistake.

Using the word order you used, the sentence would be:

> The first step to correct a mistake is patience.